# How to get Resharper to allow underscores in method names but only in Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

I know that there is a way to do this, but I can't find it again.

So, does any one know how to allow Resharper to allow underscores in unit tests?

So, for example I want this to be OK

---

**In MyClassTest.cs**

```
public void MyMethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedResult()
{}
```

---

But I want this to flag:

---

**In MyClass.cs**

```
public void MyPoorly_Named_Method()
{}
```

---

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This post demonstrates how to configure this: http://atombrenner.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-change-resharper-naming-style.html

**UPDATE:** The [Machine.Specifications](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) testing framework extends ReSharper to allow for custom naming styles for the tests/specs. Very cool; wish other frameworks did likewise. http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/02/11/resharper-naming-style-for-machine-specifications/

Comment: Note: The above link just turns naming validation off for test methods (which is a good first step). I would still love to find a way to get Resharper to allow UpperCamel with Underscore (e.g. MyMethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedResult)

Comment: @jsalwen, ReSharper 7 has a new setting called `UpperCamelCase_UnderscoresTolerant` that lets you keep "Enable inspections" checked while still allowing underscores in your test methods.

Comment: @asbjornu I finally upgrade to ReSharper 7 and it is working. I added Project Layers for my unit testing projects. ReSharper | Manage Options - team share. In the Layers, I modified the C# Naming for the Methods, properties and events.

Answer (score 3):

The [AgentSmith plugin](http://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/) for Resharper gives you this level of control over naming.